# Is the term "Power" meaningful?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, power

As far as my intuition of Force goes, I believe it is a kind of 'field' (that was not the most precise of ways to describe it!)
Like say, a force of 5 N acts on a 1 kg block. It produces an acceleration of 5 m/s² on it. Now how long it accelerates depends on **how long the field exists.** In other words, *if I stop the force at anytime, the acceleration will stop simultaneously, too.*

Now let's come to work. Work is done by a force. And the *work done by a force* translates into *the energy gained by the body on which the force acts.* The quantitative way of accounting for the work we do is, in simpler terms, multiplying, the force we applied into the work, with the net output, viz. displacement.

We see that the existence of force is time dependent. That means force may exist for a **definite period** in time. So thus should work. And thus should energy! Energy, thereby, is much like a 'field' - much like a **phenomenon** that exists as long as its "sidekick", force, exists.

Finally, power. What are we trying to do in case of power? Divide energy by time? Why? Why are we trying to *distribute a phenomenon (energy) into parcels of time?* Why then are we not distributing force in the same way? How does it make sense?

(Edit: I have kind of built a heuristic (?) explanation for myself. I want to see if that is correct. A little indication of your thoughts would do.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Field has a specific definition in physics. You can have force fields, and energy density can be a field, but I don’t think I have ever seen energy as a field.

> Finally, power. What are we trying to do in case of power? Divide energy by time? Why? Why are we trying to distribute a phenomenon (energy) into parcels of time?

We take the time derivative of work to find out how quickly the energy is transferred. If your phone holds a certain amount of energy in its battery then power tells you if you can charge your phone while you eat or if you have to charge it while you sleep. To me, that is certainly meaningful.

> Why then are we not distributing force in the same way?

We certainly can. We can take as many time derivatives of any quantity as we like. The time derivative of acceleration is called jerk.

Comment: Is the concept of power related to work and therefore related only with kinetic energy as a form of energy?